# MySQL won't restart on CentOS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I try to restart mysql, I got the following error:

ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL SUCCESS!

I can log in and use mysql from here, but any changes done to the `my.cnf` are not updated since  mysql did not actually stop when I tried to restart it.

When I try to stop it using service mysql stop, it gives me the following error:

ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

I am running `CentOS 6.5`, and my MySQL server is `MariaDB 10.0.` Everything was running just fine and not sure just now I have this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424863/error-mysql-manager-or-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found-qnap

Comment: Unless you've modified and recompiled MySQL, or are having the issue while coding against it in some fashion, this is probably better suited to SuperUser or ServerFault (if in a professional capacity). Both sites are likely to have more thorough, helpful answers.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I just found the id process for mysql on CentOS, killed it, then started MySQl again. This solved my problem.