# How to resolve this MySQL error in Mac OS X Sierra?

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I have been trying to reset the root password for MySQL on my Mac OS X Sierra and I cannot believe I can't find documentation for this anywhere that can resolve my problem.

The first error I got when I tried to access my database is this:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I figured I would completely remove MySQL and install it again with brew but when I tried with mysql_secure_installation and I get this:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Also when I try to run:

```
mysql.server stop
```

I get this error:

```
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

Comment: how did you do the installation?

Comment: @nogad, brew install mysql

Answer (score 0):

On mac, I think you have to use `root` as a password.

Comment: when i try root as a password I get this error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score 0):

1. open mysqld_safe

   `mysql.server stop`

   `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
2. open a new terminal

   `mysql -uroot -p`

   `use mysql;`

   `update user set password=PASSWORD('123456') where user="root";`

   `flush privileges;`

   `quit;`
3. close mysqld_safe terminal
4. restart mysql

   `mysql.server start`

   `mysql -uroot -p`

   `123456`

Comment: I have tried mysql.server stop before and I got this error:  ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

Comment: ps -ef | grep mysqld ;
kill -9 num

Comment: I killed the process and I still get this: ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

Comment: see :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424863/error-mysql-manager-or-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found-qnap