# Failed to Start Mysql with Error Code : PID file could not be found

Tags: mysql

I have an Apache server and I can not start MYSQL after restarting the server. When I apply "service mysql start" or "service mysql restart" I receive this error on SSH :

```
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/server.xxx.org.pid).                                          [FAILED]
```

I checked error log and errors are below :

```
2018-08-20 15:43:44 8511 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mysql/db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-08-20 15:43:44 8511 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table './mysql/db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, did you try googling the error and looking up results? E.g. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/480889/mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found) might help. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424863/error-mysql-manager-or-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found-qnap) also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found! QNAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424863/error-mysql-manager-or-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found-qnap)